# How do I pass the UIButton pressed from my custom UIControl to my view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontrol

I have a Custom `UIControl` with 3 `UIButton`s:

[image: 3 UIButton]

This `UIControl` is embeded in a `UIView` (the Yellow Rectangle) inside a view controller:

[image: UIView]

Every button has a different tag (tag1, tag2, tag3). I need to identify which button is pressed in the view controller.

I'm trying to use `sendActionsForControlEvents` in my `UIControl` to send it to the view controller.

```
[self.button1 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button2 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.button3 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I don't know how to receive it in my view controller and how to identify which button is pressed.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *tabsCollection;` in my UIControl.

Then in my ViewController I create a loop to iterate this IBOutletCollection and adding an action on each button to control the touch event.

```
    for (button in self.customTabsComponent.tabsCollection) {
        [button addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(tabPressed:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define the responsibilities.
If you develop a custom control that manages a collection of buttons it should be responsible for receiving the actions in those buttons and forwarding them to the view controller via its own interface.

Your view controller should have no responsibility of managing those buttons at all.

Otherwise, if the responsibility of managing the buttons, hence the code, is inside your view controller, then your custom control is not self-contained, not a reusable control. You simply won't be able to use it with another view controller without copy-pasting that code inside your view controller that makes the button work.

Now, if you custom control is a subclass of UIControl you cannot use `sendActionsForControlEvents` to pass information which button was tapped, since this interface is designed to have one action, but for different event types. That you need is different actions, or some kind of additional information that indicated which buttons was tapped.

Look at `UIAlertController` for example. One of the ways would be to implement a dynamic array of actions, which would be created in your view controller, passed to your custom control and invoked by the buttons. Your buttons would need to allocated dynamically inside your custom control. A bit more work, but this would be the most appropriate approach.

If you want to have a static set of buttons, you can add properties of block type to your custom control. Different buttons would invoke different blocks.

Alternatively, you can make a new delegate protocol and pass the index of pressed button, see UIAlertViewDelegate. This is a bit old school approach, which was used before blocks became available.